# How to change the output encoding of Oracle command line tools to UTF8?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, command-line, encoding, utf-8

I am using a german oracle 11.2.0g install, which has some command line tools communicating with some non-ascii characters (ü, ö, etc.). These are written out in iso8859-1 encoding, but I need them as utf-8 for some scripting. Is it possible?

Additional info:

- OS: german windows 7 x64
- Tools: command line tools in the bin/ directory of the oracle install, f.e. lsnrctl and like
- Scripting language: mostly cmd.exe

Language-specific output is okay, it gives the german output without any problem. The only problem is that it comes in iso8859-1 and not in utf-8.

It were converted by an iconv command from a cygwin, but I used this only as a last resort. The best were if I were able to set somehow the utf-8.

Another tools (f.e. tools from cygwin) work without any problem.

Comment: What command-line tools? What operating system? What scripting language? Should be fine if the NLS settings are correct.

Comment: @GrumpyPhil Thank you your comment, I extended the question with the needed infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much - I found the solution.

First, the output encoding of the Oracle command line tools can be controlled by

- either the NLS_LANG environment variable (in my situation, a value of GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8 was needed)
- or through the registry by the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\NLS_LANG`

Thank you very much for all - I leave this question to make the googlers of the future happier. :-)